# Laravel query builder updating field based on select count from another table

Tags: laravel

I have a `Post` and for each post there are multiple `Likes` in the `likes` table. I have created a `total_likes` field in the `Posts` table and I want to update it with the total number of likes from the `likes` table, in one statement. I current have this:

```
        DB::table('posts as p')
            ->update(['total_likes' => function($query) {
                $query->select(DB::raw('COUNT(*)'))
                    ->from('likes as l')
                    ->where(DB::raw('p.id = l.post_id'))
                    ->groupBy('l.post_id');
            }]);
```

But I am getting an error:

> Object of class Closure could not be converted to string

I'm essentially trying to run:

```
UPDATE posts SET total_likes = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM likes WHERE likes.post_id = posts.id GROUP BY id);
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using Laravel Models and Relationships? Would be as simple as `$post->total_likes = count($post->likes());`

Comment: I'm doing this in a migration, trying to update all the likes in one statement. Doing it one by one through models will run many sequel statements in a loop and I'm trying to a avoid that.

Comment: Hmm. I see. Do you know what line is causing the above noted error? Also you can shorten some of your syntax: `select(DB::raw())` to `selectRaw()` and `where(DB::raw())` to `whereRaw()`

Comment: Thanks for the shortened syntax, didn't know about those! So I've tried `dd()` inside the anonymous function and it doesn't die, so it not running it. Does the `update` not accept anonymous functions?

Comment: Yeah, I think your conclusion is right. `update(["total_likes" => function()...]);` doesn't seem to be valid. I'm honestly not sure how to get around this. Worst case scenario, you could always use a `DB::statement("UPDATE posts SET total_likes = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM likes WHERE likes.post_id = posts.id GROUP BY id);")`

Comment: That's probably for the best then, thanks for your help though.